# Adding another item to collection object

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

```
State:
<html:select property="product.stateId" size="1" onchange="loadProducts();loadProducts2();">
    <html:options collection="stateList" property="id" labelProperty="name"/>
</html:select>
```

I want to add another option to the list of states such as, "Please select state," in the drop down menu.  I think I need to modify the Java collection object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `<html:option>` tag which represents that. The [TLDDOC](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/options.html) allows that:

> This tag can be used multiple times within a single `<html:select>`  element, either **in conjunction with** or instead of one or more `<html:option>`  or `<html:optionsCollection>` elements.

Comment: Do you put an input tag inside option?

Comment: Huh? How is this comment related to this question/answer? In the future just ask a new question for every new and independent question. At any way, this is not possible as per the HTML specification. If you want a *combobox* (an editable dropdown), you'll have to look for a JavaScript flavored solution. Struts doesn't have such a component out of the box. You can find [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+combobox) several examples based on [jQuery](http://jquery.com) JS library.